# AmazonSQSClient delete all queues

Tags: c#, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

Is it possible to delete all queues created in Amazon SQS?

`AmazonSQSClient.DeleteQueue(QueueUrl)` method deletes only one queue and for this I need to provide QueueUrl. I want to delete all queues without providing QueueUrls.

Comment: if its not on the api client, its not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's only one way to delete all the queues is to firstly call listqueues then loop over that list and delete all the queues.

following is the c# sdk code for listing queues
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/

Note: only 1000 queues can be retrieved through this call.